# Using HTTP keep alive to access server behind NAT

Tags: android, apache, http, nat, keep-alive

I would like to connect to a client application running on Android devices which are running on NAT'd networks. Basically, I would like to run my own WebKey server (www.androidwebkey.com) which runs a web server on the Android phone. 
I would prefer not to run SSH tunnels or VPNs if I can avoid it. So my question is, how do people like 'Log Me In', 'Web Key' etc work? 
I have the following topology :

Android \

Android ---  ISP/MNO NAT -- My Public Web Server ----My ISP NAT --- Me (Using a web browser)

Android /

Each Android is running a web server in effect, although this could just be a VNC server. I just need to be able to get onto them remotely.

I have googled and googled but I am struggling to find information on it. Obviously it is possible because it is exactly how Web Key and Log Me In work. 
I believe I have to intiate a HTTP connection to a my public server from the Android devices and use 'Keep Alive' headers, but I am not sure how I then connect through my public web server to the end client. Can I just connect to the port on the web server that is assigned to this particular Android handset?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I'll contribute an answer since I didn't see one. They usually have a component on a public server which marries the client and the server. So basically the client connects to the component, the server also connects to the component, and the component proxies the communication between the client and the server.

I won't go into details for now since the question is old, but that should give the basic idea. In some instances the connection from the client to that component is initiated on demand through a request on another channel, in other cases it's constantly maintained.

So in these cases, it's really not a point-to-point connection, it passes through a central location.